# Streaming my docker container gui activities over rtsp

Tags: docker

I would like to know if I can live-stream/record my docker container's activities.

Let's say that I have 3 running containers of ubuntu with GUI that's making some Puppeteer activities and killing himself once did.

I guess I'll need to run some server that transmits the activities via RTSP protocol to the external network, but then I'll face the port conflict if I will not set it right, so I've thought about recording the activity and saving it on a shared volume.

Is it possible to perform such a thing?
And if so how?
How can I tell the container to kill himself once the Puppeteer's finished because `--rm` will not kill it because it is still recording the screen.

Comment: A Docker container just runs a process; Docker doesn't have any native concept of a "GUI".  Would a full virtual machine with a simulated display system better meet your needs?

Comment: I want to run automation that written in puppeteer with headed mode and record it, I could have like 100 automation at the same time, so it must be dynamic, can you please explain more about your idea?